# TV show (or made for TV movie) with a human male dating an alien female

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching something on the Sci-Fi channel when I was younger, of what seemed to be a really bad TV show or made-for-TV movie that took place in "THE FUTURE!!" and had two young adults in a relationship, one human male, and one alien female.  I believe the female was bald, but I distinctively remember the alien girl had what looked like leopard spots on her back - and the guy got a tattoo resembling them to try to fit in with his alien girlfriend.  Somehow, showing one's partner their spots seemed to be some sort of mating ritual (like I said, it was bad).  If I remember correctly, while the guy thought his partner would be impressed, instead the female seemed to be offended that the guy got the tattoo, but nonetheless they mated anyway (If I remember correctly there was some cheesy "Have you ever had sex with an alien before?" line that went with this).

I also happen to remember that they would play music together, I think the guy played a keyboard while the girl played some sort of [wind controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_controller).  It was some new-agey electronica stuff (typical 90s FUTURE MUSIC!!).  I think they were playing music together and this led to their mating encounter.

If I remember correctly, it felt modern when I watched it in the late 90s/early 00s, so I think it was from around that time. It's probably not much to go on, and I think it was just one small scene in the show/movie, and I have no idea if it was even related to the main plot or not, probably making it even harder to identify, but I was hoping someone might have some idea.

Answer (score 22):

The movie is called [Alien Nation](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/AlienNation) (warning, TvTropes link). First it was a movie, then it was a tv show.

> Alien Nation (1988) is a Buddy Cop movie with a Sitcom twist: the
>   minority partner is a space alien, part of a ship of "Newcomers" who
>   ended up on Earth when the slave ship they were being transported on
>   crash-landed. After Det. Matthew Sykes' partner is killed in a
>   shootout, he is partnered with Sam Francisco (whom he insists on
>   calling "George"), the first Newcomer detective. While investigating
>   the death of Sykes' partner, they uncover a dangerous Newcomer drug.
>
> The television series, based on the film Alien Nation, lasted for 22
>   episodes from September, 1989 to May, 1990. Five television movies
>   were later produced, released between 1994 and 1997.

Aliens (called Newcomers or EnCies) who are bald and have spots, were a slave species to different alien overlords and are extremely strong compared to humans.

In one of more memorable episodes of the tv series Det. Matthew dates the daughter of his alien partner Sam Francisco and they have to take classes together which teach them mating habits of humans and aliens so they can have safe sex. Turns out that safe sex means different thing to aliens, because aliens have spots all over their bodies and if the female is not put in the proper mood and relaxed (by playing music) enough, touching those spots during love making produces extremely violent reaction. In fact, the first time they try to make love his alien lover accidentally cracks two of his ribs because he refused to go to classes and thought he could just improvise it and everything will be fine, despite the warnings from his partner Sam that it is a very bad idea, since humans are much squishier than aliens. He is considered lucky to have survived at all, because she could have snapped his neck or worse (it is an instinctive reaction, they literally can't control it). The name of the episode is: [Alien Nation: Body and Soul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVrU23WI2g&t=14m05s), you can see the first attempt.

The talk with his partner Sam before the incident went something like this:

> Mat: You know that I will be gentle and caring lover, right?
>
> Sam: That's not the point. The point is that you don't know what
>   you're doing and I don't want my daughter to accidentally kill my
>   partner during sex.

Interesting things, which might help other identification questions:

For aliens, sea water is like hydrochloric acid, it burns and dissolves them.

They get drunk from spoiled milk, it is like alcohol to them.

Certain laundry detergents produce intoxicating effects on them. The slavemaster aliens produced the drug similar to detergent to keep Newcomers compliant. The plot point of the movie is when one of the aliens approaches human gang and they modify laundry detergent to be much more potent and act as a drug used for control. The drug produces "high" but results in increased strength and violence.

Opening theme:

Comment: Another fun bit I remember from the books is that nervousness causes their feet to swell.

Comment: I remember his partner having some kind of relationship with a Newcomer in his building, but not one with the daughter.

Comment: I might be misremembering some details. Feel free to improve the answer if I am wrong. I am pretty certain this is the answer to the question, though.

Comment: Oh god I forgot about that series.  I kind of liked it, but didn't see very many episodes.  I remember a later one where the Human - Newcomer relationship is progressing but the protagonist ends up coming to work with his neck in a brace or something.

Comment: You description sounds REALLY close, but the trailer does not look like what I saw at all.  I'll have to watch the episode in question to be sure.  Do you know what episode it was? EDIT: I see you posted it already

Comment: Okay, I watched the clip - this was definitely not it.  1989 is a bit too early of a production I think, this seemed to be something that was made in the late 90s/early 00s.  I have a feeling what I watched is something even more obscure, and lower quality than this (Alien Nation doesn't look half bad actually).

The male partner showing off his tattoo that mimicked his female partners' spots, then the partner being slightly offended, was the part I remember most, besides them playing music together, and the spots were on the lower back and not the head if I remember correctly.

Comment: The spots are all over the body. He did tattoo the spots in one of the episodes.  Check this made for tv movie created from the tv series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVrU23WI2g&t=35m52s

Comment: I mean, made for tv movies were being released from 1994 to 1997. That fits your timeline completely. On the other hand, it could be even more obscure show. On what channel did you watch it?

Comment: Matt (the cop) dated Kathy, a Newcomer scientist who lived in his apartment building. She was friends with George and his family. George also had a teenage daughter named Emily.

Comment: @jo1storm I am pretty sure it was on Sci-Fi, but I'm not 100% sure on that.  I really don't think it was network TV.  I can accept there might be a possibility that it could be a different episode of this show, but the scene at 8:25 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVrU23WI2g&t=8m25s) was definitely not the scene I watched.  It did not seem to be taking place in a bedroom but instead in a music studio (there was no actual sex or precursor to sex on camera, they simply discussed that they were going to do it, unlike in that clip where they're cuddling on the couch beforehand)

Comment: It definitely wasn't the scene at the end of the movie either - I want to say whatever I watched had a completely different aesthetic to it - I think it was supposed to take place in a more distant future as opposed to this which seems to be set not more than 50 years ahead.  

It is very coincidental that they have those spots on their back - but the scene I remember I think the spots were all on the lower back.  Also, one of they key details I do remember is the female was playing some sort of electric clarinet/wind controller.  The music was very synthy and mellow as well.

Comment: Also, I would say that the two partners were much younger than Matt and Kathy - late teens or very early adult.  Additionally, I believe the movie/show was much more 'serious' in tone than this, or maybe 'artistic' is the word I'm looking for, I don't think the buddy-cop aesthetic fits it.  Granted, however, I didn't see much of it, so it's possible I saw something that had a different tone than the rest of the show.

Comment: I don't want to speculate too much, but I think it's probably much more likely what I saw was more of an anthology type show, i.e. Outer Limits or Twilight Zone, than a long-running opera like this.  That's just speculation though and not anything I know for sure.

Comment: Check this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_(American_TV_series)

Comment: That looks promising - I'll comb through it and see if anything looks like it.  I know it wasn't animated for sure so that should cut out about half of those.